# Inheriting template constructor and error C2600 in MSVC 2017

Tags: c++, templates

I have encountered compilation error on VS 2017 15.9.4 (toolset v141), which used to work with VS 2015 (toolset v140). The problem is in inheriting templated constructor from base class.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class IAttribute {
public:
    template <
        typename U = T,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_default_constructible<U>::value>::type
    >
    IAttribute() {}

    IAttribute(T* value) {
    }

private:
    T* m_value;
};

class AttributeInt : public IAttribute<int> {
public:
    using IAttribute<int>::IAttribute;

    AttributeInt();
};

AttributeInt::AttributeInt() : IAttribute<int>(nullptr) {

}

int main() {
    AttributeInt qq;
}
```

In latest VS I get the error:

**error C2600: 'AttributeInt::AttributeInt': cannot define a compiler-generated special member function (must be declared in the class first)**

After a while, I have found that moving `AttributeInt()` constructor implementation to the class definition body fixes the error.

```
class AttributeInt : public IAttribute<int> {
public:
    using IAttribute<int>::IAttribute;

    AttributeInt() : IAttribute<int>(nullptr) {}
};
```

This does not however fix my problem, because in my project I need to construct derived class, which is dependent on this class. Any ideas how to fix this problem **without moving the implementation**?

Anyway, the original code works on GCC 8.2, clang 7.0.0, zapc++ 2017.08 and MSVC 2015.

Comment: Why are you using a template constructor function in the interface, while not using the template type somewhere with the implementation at all? You might try at least to give the derived default constructor the same signature as templated function.

Comment: _"I need to construct derived class, which is dependent on this class."_ Well, would the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) solve your problem?

Comment: I have cut all the unnecessary code, to make the problem more readable. This is how the classes are structured with many other classes and templates in between. I want to disable default constructor if the template type does not have a default constructor - this is because I call something like `T()` inside the abstract class. There are also bunch of other constructors which I would like to inherit, but this one I would like to override. So something like inherit all except this could work.

Comment: AFAIK your SFINAE in default constructor of `IAttribute` cannot work because there is no deduction.

Comment: @NikitaKniazev you are right, there was another template deduction parameter `U = T` and then `U` was used in place instead. Wasn't expecting anyone to notice that - I was trying to simplify the code and show only the problematic part.

Comment: That's why StackOverflow asking guides talk about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have reduced your code to this https://godbolt.org/z/7bJemX and it show that it is most likely an MSVC bug. If you move constructor definition into the class body the error disappears.

Answer (score 1):

It is confirmed as a bug in VS 2017 and it is fixed in VS 2019 16.0.0 Preview 1 -  [confirmed here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/415602/inheriting-template-constructor-and-error-c2600-in.html). Anyway, thanks for help!